# centos mongodb package not signed

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

ok this might be a stupid question and this is because centos is not part of my "strong points list" but i am trying to install mongodb and mongodb-server

i followed the steps found here
[a link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#configure-package-management-system-yum)!

they missed a step ... what happens if after centos downloads the packages ... it tells me that they are not signed

i also tried importing this gpg key (as a last desperate attempt before coming here)
[a link](http://docs.mongodb.org/10gen-gpg-key.asc)!

so how do i get pass this? :(
thanks,
Rares

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the package is not signed. It is planned to be done in the future, and the relevant tracking ticket for the implementation of signing is [SERVER-8770](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8770) (for watching and voting purposes) but there is no definite timeframe for implementation as of writing this response.

Hence, you must install with `gpgcheck=0` for the time being as noted on the page you linked to: [Install MongoDB on Redhat/CentOS/Fedora](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#configure-package-management-system-yum)

Comment: i had an error in mongodb.repo .... namely GPcheck instead of GPGcheck :) your answer forced me to double check :) thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me to ignore "package not signed" message:

```
yum install --nogpgcheck <your-package-name>
```

Changing gpgcheck to 0 in /etc/yum.conf didn't help. Security warning: you should use this option *ONLY* if you trust the installation sources.